# Center me beneath the frame title in Beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, beamer-metropolis

I'm new, but do believe I have tried to answer this on my own.  I wish to center an image vertically within the space beneath the frametitle.  The standard centering it appears centers on the frame, creating more blank space beneath an image than above the image.  I know the addition of some filling space, or overlaying a picture could fix this, but is there an automatic way?

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}{none}

\usetheme[background=dark]{metropolis}           

\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}{}
\title{}
\date{}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Center me}

\centering
     \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image}


\end{frame}   



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Are you talking about `beamer`?

Comment: I am.  Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `\vfill` what you are looking for? The difference is however hard to see.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[c]
        \frametitle{normal centred frame}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{vfill frame}
        \vfill
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
        \vfill
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

In case of the `metropolis` theme, things are a little bit more complicate. Even empty, the footline, as defined by this theme takes space. You don't see it, but the image is centred between the title and the footline. A workaround would be to define an empty footline:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}{none}

\usetheme[background=dark]{metropolis}           

\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}{}
\title{}
\date{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Center me}
        \vfill
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
        \vfill
    \end{frame}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't seem to work for theme I want to use.  I see how it works in the generic theme.  I appreciate the effort.  I guess I'll have to live with it, or choose another theme.

Comment: @Anderson Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question, including the theme? There is probably some way to do this.

Comment: I got it.  I think.  Thanks for being patient.

Comment: @Anderson See the edit.

Comment: That is absolutely outstanding.  Thank you so much.  I've enjoyed learning this, and this kind of support gives me hope in mankind.  I'll come up with a more difficult question next time.